# Include files during publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I want to include some files from different project during publish.
    So for that in my file :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<CallTarget Targets="PublishWinService" />
</Target>
<Target Name="PublishWinService">
<Copy 
      SourceFiles ="$(SolutionDir)..\References\Test\**\*"   
      DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

But it gives me error saying that :

> Unable to copy file
>   "C:\PrakashSourceCode\Source\Abc
>   ..\References\Test***" to
>   "C:\PrakashSourceCode\Source\ Abc\Abc.web*".
>   Illegal characters in path.

Now i changed it to:

```
     <Copy SourceFiles="@(YourFilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="C:\Test56\" />
        <!--DestinationFolder="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"-->
</Target>
```

But during publish iam not able to see files and during build i can see files.

Comment: Did you manually edit this file?

Comment: There are 2 dots before References directory. Did you add this dots? If yes, why 2 dots?

Comment: That specify the location as i want to have the root name

Comment: yes, but I think it doesn't work correctly. **C:\PrakashSourceCode\Source\Lancet.Engine** is your SolutionDir and your 2 dots comes after SolutionDir. What is your files path that you want to copy?

Comment: did you try 
SourceFiles ="$(SolutionDir)\..\References\Test\\*\*\\*.\*"

Comment: So the 2 dots will trim Lance.Engine and the now the path will be C:\PrakashSourceCode\Source\References\Test and it will copy all the file from that folder.This works even in post build events but not here why i don't know?

Comment: Suresh i tried that too

Answer (score 3):

You may try if this simple solution works for you (It will only work if you can modify and save the .prj file):

**Right Click on the file(s) which you want to publish** -> **Properties** -> **Copy to Output Directory**.

The default value is **Do not copy**. Change this to **Copy always** or **Copy if newer**.

This will ensure that the file is in the build directory. You may pick it up from there.